# UIViewController Containers in storyboard

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller, containers, uistoryboard

I have a main UIViewController that contains a container view. I embedded a UIViewController with a green background  and a button inside the container. The button should load a UIViewController with a red background inside the container. The problem is when I press the button that loads the red UIViewController the entire screen becomes red. What I want is to change the container view only.

The end goal is to have multiple buttons in the green and red UIViewcontrollers that load different UIViewControllers inside the container without taking over the entire screen. I'm trying to do this in storyboard.

Sorry I can't embed the image in the post because I have less than 10 reputation points. Here's a link to an image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl7ME.jpg

Comment: do you want the red view to replace the green view? or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: are you trying to make square inside square inside square etc ? like here: https://otvet.imgsmail.ru/download/385023ba67ed69caf8b11fc3fbaf9f09_i-12205.jpg . like you are trying to call every time smaller view controller from the parent view controller?

Comment: I want the red square to replace the green square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then making UIViewController next to container view, try to put navigation controller and that navigation controller will load UIViewController in it.[image]

Use push segue to insert new view controllers.
Hope this will work.

Comment: Not sure if this should be a new question: If I want to call a function that is in the main white UIViewcontroller from the green UIViewController how would I do that? I tried var controller = main(), controller.update(). where update is a method in the main uiviewcontroller

Comment: ask this in a separate question.